# What should I be using between $() and jQuery()?

Tags: jquery

I was told that using jQuery() was accepted on more browsers then $().
But $() is so much faster to use.
I searched the web for info about which one is better but couldn't find anything relevant.

So my questions are: Which one is better? Why? Is there a difference between them? Can someone share a link to somewhere that explains it?

Thank you

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/

Comment: You only *need* to use `jQuery()` if `$()` is used by something else, like Prototype.

Comment: so many answers x_x Thank you for the answers!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I was told that using jQuery() was accepted on more browsers then $().

That is completely wrong.

The only reason to use `jQuery` is if some other library has set `$` to something else.

If you're writing a plugin, best practice is to use `jQuery` so that people who use these other libraries can still use your plugin.
You can wrap your code in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to use `$` *inside* the plugin.

Comment: w00t! You are almost at 300k ^_^

Comment: @BrianMacKay ha ha.Please try tommarow :P

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference.

They do the same thing.

The only time *really* one might use `jQuery` instead of `$` is when the `$` variable is conflicted with another library.

Answer (score 1):

`$` and `jQuery()` both point to the window.jQuery object, so the same object. The reason some scripts use jQuery instead of $ is to evit conflicts with other libraries such as different versions of jquery which both also use the $ variable.

Answer (score 1):

`$` and `jQuery` are exactly the same thing, meaning that they point to the same function.

The only reason to use `jQuery` is, eventually, to avoid conflicting with frameworks that also use the `$` as their main function (prototype.js I think... zepto perhaps, I don't know what other).

In case you know there is a conflict, you can use the aptly named [`noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) method on jQuery, which will release the `$` and reset it to its previous value.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference just **to avoid conflicts  with other libraries**

[**jQuery()**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/) — which can also be written as **$()** — searches through the **DOM** for any elements that match the provided selector and creates a new **jQuery object** that references these elements.

$ and jQuery both point to the [**window.jQuery**](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/basics-what-s-the-difference-between-and-jquery-and-other-n00b-qs) object, so they are one and the same. the reason some scripts use jQuery instead of $ is to prevent conflicts with other libraries such as prototype or different versions of jquery which both also use the $ variable.